# Rails duplicate of same form in view leaves fields empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a view associated with one model but there are multiple versions of the same form that are hidden until a jquery function shows them. When I try to submit one, all the fields are empty.

Here is the view in question:

```
= form_for @rfi do |f|
    - if @rfi.errors.any?
      #error_explanation
        h2 = "#{pluralize(@rfi.errors.count, "error")} prohibited this rfi from being saved:"
        ul
          - @rfi.errors.full_messages.each do |message|
            li = message

    .field
      = f.label :svg_ref, "SVG PO Number"
      = f.text_field :svg_ref

    .field
      = f.label :vendor_ref, "Vendor SO Number"
      = f.text_field :vendor_ref

    .field
      = f.label :due
      = f.text_field :due
      = f.hidden_field :rfi_type, value:"order"
    .actions 
      = f.submit



.rfi_type.rfi_type_quote
  = form_for @rfi do |f|
    - if @rfi.errors.any?
      #error_explanation
        h2 = "#{pluralize(@rfi.errors.count, "error")} prohibited this rfi from being saved:"
        ul
          - @rfi.errors.full_messages.each do |message|
            li = message

    .field
      = f.label :reference, "Quote number"
      = f.text_field :reference
      = f.hidden_field :rfi_type, value:"quote"
    .field
      = f.label :due
      = f.text_field :due
    .actions 
      = f.submit
```

This is the Jquery involved

```
$ ->
    $(".rfi_type").hide()
    $(".rfi_type_order").show()


    $("input:radio[name=rfi_type]").change ->
        $(".rfi_type").hide()
        $(".rfi_type_"+$(this).val()).show()
        return
    return
```

Comment: Sounds like your jQuery function is doing something invalid.

Comment: @sevenseacat I just added the jquery for inspection, all it does is show or hide the form.

Comment: Please, give more information.  What params does your server receive when you submit a form (see in console) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe 'one' of the problems you may be facing is your use of the hidden_field with the same name. I would suggest you restructure both your haml and coffee-script to something like this

```
$ ->
  $("#quote-fields").hide()

  $("input:radio[name=rfi_type]").change ->
    $(".show-hide-container").hide()
    type = $(this).val()
    $("#" + type + "-fields" ).show()
    $("#rfi_type-field").val(type)


= form_for @rfi do |f|
    - if @rfi.errors.any?
      #error_explanation
        h2 = "#{pluralize(@rfi.errors.count, "error")} prohibited this rfi from being saved:"
        ul
          - @rfi.errors.full_messages.each do |message|
            li = message

    #order-fields.show-hide-container
      .field
        = f.label :svg_ref, "SVG PO Number"
        = f.text_field :svg_ref
      .field
        = f.label :vendor_ref, "Vendor SO Number"
        = f.text_field :vendor_ref

    #quote-fields.field.show-hide-container
      = f.label :reference, "Quote number"
      = f.text_field :reference  

    .field
      = f.label :due
      = f.text_field :due

    = f.hidden_field :rfi_type, value: "order", id: "rfi_type-field"
    .actions 
      = f.submit
```